# I just bought TF2 as part of the Valve Complete Pack. Where's my Proof of Purchase helmet?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

I bought a Valve Complete Pack license off an external site ([Here](http://www.gameshop.playkampfschaf.de/category/3902/valve-complete-pack-steam-key/), to be exact), which came with TF2 (which I hadn't downloaded before).

I'm pretty sure I have a premium account because my backpack has a lot of "pages", but I don't have that Proof of Purchase helmet that I understand I'm supposed to get. Is some extra step required? Or would I have had to buy the game from Steam, not just activate it there?

Comment: Have you launched the game yet? Promotion items don't get added to your inventory until you launch the game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Official TF2 wiki](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Proof_of_Purchase):

> This hat is given to players who purchased Team Fortress 2 before the
>   Über Update on June 23, 2011, those who receive a gift of the game,
>   and those who activate a retail copy of the game, such as purchasing
>   the Orange Box.

If you look in the [Notes](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Proof_of_Purchase#Notes) section, it'll say:

> Purchasing the Orange Box or Valve Complete Pack on **Steam** will still grant users the item.

So I'm assuming you'd need to have bought the pack on Steam in order to receive the hat.

However, this seems a bit contradicting with

> ...and those who activate a retail copy of the game...

since that implies that activating a copy of the game will grant you the hat. I do think however that that only implies when you get a boxed copy of Team Fortress 2.

I think that you can only get the Proof of Purchase hat, along with all other premium features, when you:

- Activate a boxed copy of Team Fortress 2
- Receive a gift of the boxed copy of Team Fortress 2
- Buy the Valve Complete Pack on Steam

Otherwise, you can't get the hat.

Comment: > those who activate a retail copy of the game

Doesn't that count?

Comment: I missread, I'm editing the answer atm.

Comment: I edited the answer with (more) correct information.

Comment: OK, thanks! There go my hopes of showing off that I bought the game :P

Comment: @MadTux To be frank man, I think the PoP hat is a lame hat. Personally, I don't think it's a hat you should be showing off all that much. Just wait until you get unusuals!

Comment: How does one get them?

Comment: @MadTux [Unboxing. Lots of unboxing](http://www.kongregate.com/games/stripedypaper/tf2-crate-sim).